# add timestamp at begining of each line in telnet session

Tags: timestamps, telnet

I want to log a Telnet session with timestamp on each output line.
I tried

```
telnet machine_IP_address | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'
```

but when I have to enter login/password, it does not work.

Any idea?

Comment: Is this for a logfile, or do you want the terminal output mixed up with timestamps?

Comment: terminal output mixed with timestamp as I need to issue some commands on telenet session

Comment: On the machine you telnet into, if running bash shell add `[\D{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}]` to PS1. That will at least give you the time each system prompt was displayed.

Comment: what is PS1? sorry, I don't understand what I've to do

Comment: The variable `PS1` is the _command prompt_, i.e. whatever is printed on the terminal indicating that it is ready to accept commands. Usually, you have the `username@hostname:$` (for non-root users). This is set globally in /etc/profile but can be overriden in `~./bash_profile` (or `~./bashrc`). So, I guess @Deathgrip suggests that you put `PS1=[\D{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}]` in the machine's you telnet to`~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: That was indeed my suggestion.